# Square Connect API V2 ListCustomers not returning all customers

Tags: python, square, square-connect

I'm working with the Square Connect API V2 trying to do something very simple: list all my customers. From my Square dashboard I can see I have ~8k customers, but when using the ListCustomers endpoint, I only receive 151. Looking at my calls, it looks like I'm only getting one pagination `cursor`, from my first request and none thereafter. For reference, here is the relevant code:

```
def get_customers(api, cursor=None):
    customers = {}
    count = 0
    while cursor or count == 0:
        response = api.list_customers(cursor=cursor)
        cursor = response.cursor
        customers[count] = response.customers
        count += 1
    return customers
```

151 vs 8k is a huge difference and makes this call useless. Is this a known behavior that ListCustomers does not return all customers?

EDIT: Doing a little more digging, I found that Square separates customers into those "created by Square" and those "created by you". The ListCustomers endpoint only seems to return customers "created by you", whereas the vast majority of my customers were created by Square. So to refine the question, how can I return ALL customers, including those created by Square, from the Connect API v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your edit, **you can't**. The ListCustomers endpoint will only return customers that you have added to your Square account, either via CreateCustomer or in a Square app.

Comment: Is there a solid reasoning behind this? The system I'm working w/ has been delegating this all to Square. In the meantime, I've built a workaround using card fingerprints, which helps, but it'd still be nice to have access to all those customers Square has been creating.

Thanks for the prompt answer regardless!

Comment: There is some general reasoning about customer privacy (would you want a  merchant to have your email/phone number when you just swiped your card), but it is an area of active consideration for change.